# Poor HDFS performances: "Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror"

Tags: hadoop, io, hdfs

I'd like to submit a strange behavior while instanciating another new Hadoop cluster, on a new hardware stack.

Once everything got installed, as soon as we try to perform any I/O operation on HDFS, we can see many of these messages within the datanode logs:

```
15/01/14 22:13:07 WARN datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 6339ms (threshold=300ms)
15/01/14 22:13:26 INFO DataNode.clienttrace: src: /10.10.5.7:17276, dest: /10.10.5.4:50010, bytes: 176285, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-832581408_1, offset: 0, srvID: af886556-96db-4b03-9b5b-cd20c3d66f5a, blockid: BP-784291941-127.0.1.1-1420922413498:blk_1073742333_1531, duration: 19383299287
```

Followed by the famous one:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read (...)
```

We've suspected dual-VLAN + bonded network interfaces (2x10 GBps) ot be part of this, but, of course, we double-checked lots of these points and found nothing: `iperf`, `dd`/`hdparm`, increasing `Xmx` (8 GB), `sysbench`...
We only found that the cluster had a pretty big `await` time on its disk when running HDFS (>500ms, correlated to our log messages), but we can't explain clearly what happened.

Even if you will all suspect HDDs to be the cause of our troubles, can someone explain these log messages? We can't find anything interesting in source code,  except it occurs while doing `flush` (makes sense...).

Setup:

- Hadoop 2.6.0
- 9 Datanodes
- Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64
- 10x 1TB SAS drives
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-2~deb7u1)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

This is a cross-post from the user ML, since I've got no answer so far ;-(.

Comment: We have the same problem - what filesystem are you using? ext4?

Comment: Well, actually we've fixed that issue. This was due to our network MTU, nothing to do with the FS. Our experimental MTU was far too-large, and was causing such behaviors. Getting back to the classical values bring things back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually we've fixed that issue. This was due to our network MTU, nothing to do with the FS. Our experimental MTU was far too-large, and was causing such behaviors. Getting back to the classical values bring things back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with slow HDFS.

I managed to resolve the second error:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting
>   for channel to be ready for read (...)

by increasing DataNode Java xmx.

Hope this helps.